# How do I create a test passing badge for my yaml below

Tags: c#, github, github-actions

I am wanting to create a status badge for my unit tests, using the following yaml I see examples where its individual steps but not when its layerd out like mine.

You will see I have a step named Test below

```
# This workflow will build a .NET project
# For more information see: 
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating- 
builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-net

name: MYAPI

on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}

  push:
    branches: [ "dev-1-0-0-3" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev-1-0-0-3" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```